# Power Series Solution to Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

The equation is

$$y'' - xy' + y = 0$$

So far I have the recurrence relation -

$$a_{n+2} = \dfrac{(n-1)a_n}{(n+1)(n+2)} $$

From this -

$a_2 = \dfrac{-a_0}{2!}$

$a_3 = 0$

$a_4 = \dfrac{-a_0}{4!}$

$a_5 = 0$

$a_6 = \dfrac{-3a_0}{6!}$

and so on..

The question asks for the first five non-zero terms of a general series solution of the d.e, seperating out for $a_0$ and $a_1$

How do I compute this?

Thanks

Comment: If you've come this far, I think you already have the solution. It is $y = a_0\left(1 - \frac{1}{2!}x^2 - \frac{1}{4!}x^4 - \frac{3}{6!}x^6 - \ldots\right) + a_1x$. (I'm trusting your calculation.)

Comment: Where did the first 1 come from and also, where did the last $a_1x$ come from?

Comment: When you try to solve an ODE with the power series method, you start with assuming $y = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + \ldots$. That is how you eventually get the recurrence and solve for $a_n$. Once you know all the $a_n$, you should put them back into the assumed form of the solution that you started with.

Comment: Ok, but I still can't see where the first $a_0$ comes from, or the last $a_1$x? I didn't compute these?

Comment: These are supposed to be unknown. Your ODE is second-order, so the solution is not uniquely determined unless you give it two conditions. Note that this is the same situation as when you solve a second-order linear ODE with constant coefficients.

Comment: So there will always be an $a_0$ and $a_1x$ included no matter what the solution or how many terms it asks for?

Comment: I'm not sure if you realize that my discussion so far has nothing to do with the number of terms you're asked for. It should be easy to just cut the infinite series somewhere when you write it. You should know, however, that if you cut it and you don't write ..., what you get isn't a solution anymore.

Comment: What I'm asking is - is the first term **always** $a_0$ and is the last term always $a_1x$?

Comment: The first is always $a_0$, but the **last** term, I'm not so sure. It depends on how you define the order of terms. If you look back at the original form you started with, $y = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + \ldots$ implies $a_0$ is always the first term, $a_1x$ is always the second term, $a_2x^2$ is always the third term, and so on. But if you rearrange it to separate $a_0$ and $a_1$, then you have two sets of terms: $a_0(1 + \ldots)$ and $a_1x(1 + \ldots)$. In this particular problem, $a_1x$ becomes the *last* term because $a_3 = a_5 = \ldots = 0$.

Comment: Hmm, so then $a_0$ and $a_1x$ are always included right?

Comment: Yes. That should be clear from what I've said.

Answer (score 1):

The differential equation 
\begin{align}
y^{''} - x y^{'} + y = 0
\end{align}
can be solved via a power series of the form
\begin{align}
y(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_{n} x^{n} = a_{0} + a_{1} x + a_{2} x^{2} + \cdots .
\end{align}
It is fairly evident that
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k(k-1) a_{k} x^{k} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k-1) a_{k} x^{k}
\end{align}
which yields the equation for the coefficients
\begin{align}
a_{k+2} = \frac{ (k-1) a_{k} }{ (k+1) (k+2) }.
\end{align}
It is discovered that $a_{3} = 0 \cdot a_{1}$. Since, for $k$ being odd, say $k \rightarrow 2k+1$, 
\begin{align}
a_{2k+3} = \frac{k a_{2k+1} }{(k+1)(2k+3)}
\end{align}
it is clear that all the odd coefficients depend of $a_{3}$ for $k \geq 1$ and leads to $a_{2k+1} = 0$ for $k \geq 1$. The even $k$ values are
\begin{align}
a_{2} &= - \frac{a_{0}}{2!} \\
a_{4} &= - \frac{a_{0}}{4!} \\
a_{6} &= - \frac{(1 \cdot 3) a_{0}}{6!} \\
a_{8} &= - \frac{(1\cdot 3 \cdot 5)a_{0}}{8!} 
\end{align}
which has the general form
\begin{align}
a_{2k} = - \frac{a_{0}}{2^{k} k! (2k-1)}.
\end{align}
The series for $y(x)$ now be seen in the form
\begin{align}
y(x) = a_{0} + a_{1} x - a_{0} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{ x^{2n} }{2^{k} k! (2k-1)}.
\end{align}

The power series discovered can be evaluated as follows. Consider
\begin{align}
\partial_{x} \left( \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{ x^{2n-1} }{2^{k} k! (2k-1)} \right) &= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{ x^{2n-2} }{2^{k} k!} = \frac{1}{x^{2}}( e^{x^{2}/2} -1). 
\end{align}
Integrating both sides
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{ x^{2n} }{2^{k} k! (2k-1)} &= x \int^{x} \frac{e^{u^{2}/2} -1}{u^{2}} du = x \left[ \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2} } erfi\left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} \right) - \frac{e^{x^{2}/2}}{x} + \frac{1}{x} \right] \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2} } \cdot x \cdot erfi\left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} \right) - e^{x^{2}/2} + 1.  
\end{align}
With this series the general solution of $y(x)$ can be sen by
\begin{align}
y(x) &= a_{0} + a_{1} x - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{ x^{2n} }{2^{k} k! (2k-1)} \\
&= a_{1} x  - a_{0} \left[ \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2} } \cdot x \cdot erfi\left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} \right) - e^{x^{2}/2} \right], 
\end{align}
where $erfi(x)$ is the imaginary error function (erfi(x) = -i erf(ix)).

Comment: great explanation, if you get a chance could you check out my series problem regarding differential equations? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253729/use-series-methods-to-solve/1253733#1253733